# Can't access local programs from Python script

Tags: python, macos

I´m trying to execute locally installed programs from a Python script (OSX), but they are not found, since `/usr/local/bin` is not in the `PATH`. Running `os.environ` gives only `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

It is probably a common/simple problem, but I´ve exhausted Google, and start feeling a little stupid :-)

Comment: You need to use the abspath to the programs if they are not in the default PATH. If the program is not in the PATH of the your executing environment, then it can't find it

Comment: See comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to execute your programs (please provide us a minimal code sample)?
If you are using the `subprocess` package, you can try to provide the full path of your executable:

```py
subprocess.run(["/usr/local/bin/my_program"], ...)
```

Else, you can try to append `/usr/local/bin` to the `os.environ` list.

Comment: I´m using subprocess.getoutput(<command>). Yes, I could "hardcode" the paths, but i am trying to do it cross platform, including Windows, and then I guess I run into trouble again.

Comment: Well, you do not have other choice than asking the user of your program to configure properly its PATH value. The `os.environ` variable must have the path where to find the program. Does your program run when executed in a terminal ? If so, how do you execute your python program?